# Searching a table in Microsoft Access

Tags: database

I have spent days looking for a solution to my problem but have come up empty handed.

I am creating a database at work that contains **3** tables.

The first table is **Servers** which will contain all the servers that we (the Network Operations Center) monitor and information related to that server.

The second table is **Contacts** which will contain all the information of the people we might need to contact.

The third table is an **Intersection** table which I use to relate servers (from the servers table) to their respective owners (from the contacts table).

I have all these tables setup and i have also built a query and form that displays the information perfectly.

**Now here comes the question..**

I want to add a text box into the form into which we can enter a server name. we can then click a button next to the text box and it will search the **Servers** table and pull all the information related to that server.

**How do i get this to work?!**

I literally want it to function exactly like the search box at the bottom of my form that is built into access (to the left of the vertical scroll bar) but i just want it at the the top of and as a part of my form!

a few notes

- once this is done i will be splitting the database and hosting it on a server
- I do not want to be able to edit the database from the form

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Angus

Comment: Like this? See HansUp's answer at the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962805/filter-continuous-form-using-textbox